# Executing multiple PostGIS functions in a single query

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am brand new to PostGIS and this question is probably just due to my limited SQL experience, but what is one way to execute multiple functions sequentially in PostGIS? For example, I have vector shapefile that I want to (in this order):

1. Select by attribute
2. Multipart to single part
3. Buffer these single parts

I have completed steps 1 and 2 with the following code:

```
SELECT some_col,
    (ST_Dump(geom)).geom As geom FROM some_table
WHERE some_col= '1';
```

This brings me to part 3 - what would be a way to nest the buffer call to these now single parts?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I have updated to read as "one way" or "a way" to do something. My current approach is that I have completed tasks 1 and 2 with the code snippet provided and I am unsure how to proceed to step 3.

Comment: just wrap the buffer around the dump: ST_buffer((ST_Dump(geom)).geom, your_buffer_size) as geom

Comment: For reference, once a shapefile is loaded into the database, is no longer a shapefile -- it is a table.

Comment: @PieterB, Thanks! That was easy enough. Is that true for additional steps as well? For example, say I want to ST_collect those now buffered single parts, do I just wrap ST_buffer with ST_collect?

Comment: You have selected two of the more complicated functions because st_dump is returning many rows and st_collect is collecting many rows into one. Something like `select st_collect(a.geom) from
(select st_buffer((st_dump("GEOMETRY")).geom,1) as geom from my_table) a` should work. See also https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Collect.html

Comment: Maybe that's what you were looking for, maybe not:https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/422001/120129