# How to buffer a line with segments in PostGIS using unique segmentsize?

Tags: postgis

I want to buffer a line in PostGIS. For this purpose I created a line, split it into fixed segments (8m) and run the buffer function.

```
--CREATE TABLE line(name char(10), geom geometry);
--INSERT INTO line VALUES('line','SRID=32637;LINESTRING(423458.0 6857171.2,  423439.8 6857244.5, 423501.7 6857327.8)');

WITH 
    segmentvertex AS (
        SELECT ST_Segmentize(geom, 8) AS geom
        FROM line)

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS segment_id, st_buffer(geom, 4, 'endcap=flat join=bevel') AS segment_geom

FROM (
SELECT dmp.path,
        ST_MakeLine(dmp.geom, LEAD(dmp.geom) OVER()) AS geom

FROM segmentvertex AS s, 
LATERAL ST_DumpPoints(s.geom) as dmp
)   t

WHERE  geom IS NOT NULL
```

Somehow I cannot handle the vertexes at the corners of the line which creates bad looking transition zones. On the left hand of the picture I inserted a segment wise buffer based on output of the GRASS v.split tool in QGIS 3.1 which is more looking like expected.

[image]

How can I achieve the same result in PostGIS like in QGIS? Im using PostGIS 2.5.1

Comment: The segments are not of equal size because `st_segmentize` only adds vertices so that the distance between two vertices does not exceed the given length. By creating a new line between every vertices, you end up with smaller segments that break at every inflection point. Using `st_lineSubstring` instead (as suggest [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/361561/84870) will lead to results similar to what is on the left. BUT, in both case, if a segment happens to end on an inflection point, the buffer will look like on the right.

Comment: I want to split the line into segments with a fixed width (e.g.8m). So far I know ```st_segmentize``` just apply the segmentation based on a proportional value.

Answer (score 1):

So there are many solutions of your question and this is one of them :-).

Your case is particular and problematic, because for a linear object divided into segments at the inflection points, it is difficult to write an algorithm which will solve complex situations of behavior of buffering objects, moreover, they are complicated by values of length and width of the buffering.
As a result, for your case with your conditions and geodata, I suggest possible solutions to your question.
Pre-create custom functions ST_SnapPolygonToLine() and ST_PointsInStarPolygon(), you'll find them here on GIS Stack Exchange...
Run the SQL script:

```
WITH 
tbla AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_LineSubstring( d.geom, substart, CASE WHEN subend > 1 THEN 1 ELSE subend END) geom
FROM (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, geom, ST_Length(geom) len, 8 sublen FROM line) AS d CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT i, (sublen * i)/len AS substart, (sublen * (i+1))/len AS subend
        FROM generate_series(0, floor(d.len/sublen)::integer) AS t(i) WHERE (sublen * i)/len <> 1.0) AS d2),
tblb AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_Buffer(geom, 4,'join=mitre mitre_limit=5.0') as geom FROM tbla),
tblc AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_OffsetCurve(geom, 4) geom FROM tbla),
tbld AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_SnapPolygonToLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN tblc b ON true AND a.id=b.id),
tble AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_OffsetCurve(geom, -4) geom FROM tbla),
tblf AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_SnapPolygonToLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tbla a JOIN tble b ON true AND a.id=b.id),
tblg AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_Union(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tbld a JOIN tblf b ON true AND a.id=b.id)
SELECT a.id, ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) as geom FROM tblb a, tblg b WHERE ST_Intersects (a.geom, b.geom) AND a.id=b.id ORDER BY a.id
```

The result is shown in figure 1.
[image]

Figure 1.

If you are satisfied with smooth outlines of the buffer borders, run the following SQL script:

```
WITH 
tbla AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_LineSubstring( d.geom, substart, CASE WHEN subend > 1 THEN 1 ELSE subend END) geom
FROM (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, geom, ST_Length(geom) len, 8 sublen FROM line) AS d CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT i, (sublen * i)/len AS substart, (sublen * (i+1))/len AS subend
        FROM generate_series(0, floor(d.len/sublen)::integer) AS t(i) WHERE (sublen * i)/len <> 1.0) AS d2),
tblb AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_OffsetCurve(geom, 4) geom FROM tbla),
tblc AS (SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_OffsetCurve(geom, -4) geom FROM tbla)
(SELECT row_number() over() AS id, ST_SnapPolygonToLine(a.geom, b.geom) geom FROM tblb a JOIN tblc b ON true AND a.id=b.id)
```

The result is given in picture 2.

[image]

Figure 2.

Original spatial solutions...

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: P.S. Unfortunately - this logic will work for your geodata example, i.e. for, not much curved lines...