# How to create line substrings with fixed lengths from a line ignoring inflection vertices in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I want to split a line in segments of a fixed length (e.g. 10m) like indicated in the picture. Using the approach of `st_segmentize` [how-to-buffer-a-line-with-segments-in-postgis-using-unique-segmentsize](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/361829/how-to-buffer-a-line-with-segments-in-postgis-using-unique-segmentsize) works partially fine, but counts each inflection point as end/beginning of a line, which lead to unequal segment sizes. Using the GRASS function v.split in QGIS results in the right output [v.split](https://www.northrivergeographic.com/qgis-split-a-line-at-an-interval), so I want to know if there is a similar function/ approach in PostGIS 2.5.1.

[image]

Comment: Use a sequenced `ST_LineSubstring`. Packed into a set of PL/PgSQL functions [here](https://github.com/geozelot/postgis-addons/blob/master/SQL/st_linesubstringsbyvalue.sql), readme [here](https://github.com/geozelot/postgis-addons/blob/master/SQL/README.md#setof-geometry_dump-st_linesubstringsbylengthgeom-geometrylinestring-seg_len-float8). C function addon [here](https://github.com/geozelot/postgis-addons/tree/master/C) (needs rebuild from source). Reading that linked question, @JGHs comment still stands; `ST_Segmentize` only includes vertices so that none is further apart than the threshold!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ST_LineSubstring`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineSubstring.html) (as suggested by @geozelot in the comment):

```
-- We split the line into segment using `ST_LineSubstring`
SELECT ST_LineSubstring(geom, n/length,
  CASE
    WHEN (n+dist) < length THEN (n+dist)/length
    ELSE 1
  END) AS the_geom
FROM
  (
  -- Example line of length ~48m
  SELECT 10.0 AS dist,
         ST_Length(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0,0 20,20 40)')) AS length,
         ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0,0 20,20 40)') AS geom
  ) AS subQ
-- We cross join with a series.
CROSS JOIN generate_series(0,(floor(length/dist)*dist)::int,dist::int) AS n
```

This query will split your linestring in segment of 10m (specified by `dist`).

For each line we generate a serie that goes from `0` to `floor(len/10)*10`. In this example the line has a length of about 48m, so the serie goes from `0` to `40` with step of 10m. For the last segment of 8m: `n+dist` = `40+10` = `50`, since `50>48` we set the end fraction to `1`.

This query will also work if you have more than one line.